# Xcode 11 #colorLiteral written instead of being displayed as color

Tags: swift, xcode11

I recently updated my Xcode from 10.3 to 11.0.

I registered all the colors I am using among the app in a `Scheme.swift` file with its own struct.

Since I updated, the `#colorLiteral`s are not computed properly by Xcode in my **struct constructor** but just written as code:

**Xcode 11**
[image]

*Raw code, so you can copy/paste it in a playground*

```
import UIKit

struct Theme {
    var color1: UIColor
    var color2: UIColor
}

Theme(color1: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0),
      color2: #colorLiteral(red: 1.0, green: 1.0, blue: 1.0, alpha: 1.0))
```

Does anyone know how I can force Xcode to refresh or compute these colorLiterals so I can use the color picker as usual?

Is it not possible anymore to define a colorLiteral in a function call (here a struct init)?

---

**Edit**

It seems to be related to the fact that my `#colorLiteral`s are written in a function call, before a `,`. If I surround it by parenthesis it automatically switch to a "color picker".

Plus, it doesn't happen to the **last colorLiteral** in the call

Comment: It works on my Xcode. Try comment and uncomment the line with Command+/ key

Comment: I tried to comment/uncomment, cut+paste, nothing changes..

Comment: It is working fine for me too. No issues for me.

Comment: I have the same issue. Images also don't work for me (they don't work properly since at least 10.2, never found a workaround).

Comment: same with me on 11.1

Comment: did you ever figure out this issue? I'm running into the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Please try Color(#colorLiteral())